# DataTables cannot sort 'date' column type in Edge

Tags: javascript, datatables, microsoft-edge, datatables-1.10

When `columnDefs` is used to set a column type as 'date' the sorting breaks, but only in Edge. Firefox and Chrome continue to behave as expected.

No errors are thrown and if I remove the type it re-enables sorting as alphanumeric.

Can anybody advise why this is occuring and how I can address it?

Exact reproducable example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id='target'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Foo</th>
        <th width='200'>date</th>
        <th>bar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <script>
    console.log('script start');
      $('#target').DataTable({
        'pageLength': 100,
        'lengthMenu': [100, 150, 200],
        'data': [
          ['aaa', '30-Nov-2020', 'ccc'],
          ['aaa', '03-Nov-2020', 'ccc'],
          ['aaa', '31-Oct-2020', 'ccc'],
          ['aaa', '30-Oct-2020', 'ccc'],
          ['aaa', '06-Oct-2020', 'ccc'],
          ['aaa', '30-Sep-2020', 'ccc'],
          ['aaa', '30-Sep-2020', 'ccc'],
          ['aaa', '15-Sep-2020', 'ccc']
        ],
           "columnDefs": [
          {
            "targets": 1,
            "type": "date"
          }
        ]
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turns out that Edge has a much narrower set of valid `Date.parse` formats. Negoriating with users what they will accept.

Comment: You can remove the dashes to get a format that can be sorted - for example `06 Oct 2020` instead of `06-Oct-2020`.

Comment: @andrewjames did some brief testing and that format seems to parse single-digit day numbers as the 23rd hour of the previous day, eg: `02 Jul 2020` and `2 Jul 2020` parse as `2020-07-01T23:00:00.000Z`...

Comment: Good to know - thank you.  Messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue persists then you can also refer this example is working fine with the MS Edge browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.fn.dataTable.moment("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm a");
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                "order": [[2, "desc"]]
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>16/05/2017 05:44 pm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>15/05/2017 05:43 pm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>12/02/2017 05:43 pm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>13/05/2017 05:45 am</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>11/05/2017 05:41 pm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>13/05/2017 05:41 pm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>12/05/2017 05:41 pm</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'd hoped to avoid using the moment plugin as there'll be a whole process involved getting it approved but it seems like I'll have to in the end!

Comment: You can also try to refer to this example which is not using moment plugin and it is also working with the MS Edge browser. Ref: https://codepen.io/michelgefuni/pen/zqyLgG Let us know, whether it helps you to solve your issue or not.

Comment: @Gavin, Is the issue resolved or still persist?  If the issue is solved, I suggest you post the solution here and mark your own answer. If the issue was solved by the above answer then you can accept it as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I've marked this as answer as it absolutely works. But in our case I just negotiated the user down to a date format that worked by default without having to modify any existing plugins.