# Why date is not sorting perfectly in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have try many ways to sort date in dataTables but not working perfectly (asc or desc).
I referred to any place to find the solution but not solve.

[image]

Below are the method that I have tried but not working.

1. Use `Date Eu` plugin. [Here 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984554/sorting-date-in-datatable) , [Here 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814191/how-to-sort-datatables-with-date-in-descending-order/47939985#47939985) , [Here 3](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-eu)

**JS**

```
function loadtable(){

    var project = '';

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        crossDomain: true,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({project_id: project_id}),
        success: function(response){
            if (response.status == "Success"){
                $.each(response.data, function(key, value){
                    "<div class='table-responsive'>"+
                        "<table id='' class='table Layer1Table' style='width:100%'>"+
                            "<thead>"+
                                "<tr>"+
                                    "<th>Activity Name</th>"+
                                    "<th>Plan Start Date</th>"+
                                    "<th>Plan Finish Date</th>"+
                                    "<th>Actual Start Date</th>"+
                                    "<th>Actual Finish Date</th>"+
                                "</tr>"+
                            "</thead>";
                            $.each(value.l3_task, function(key, value1){
                                project += 
                                "<tr>"+
                                    "<td>"+value1.task_name+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+value1.task_planned_start_date+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+value1.task_planned_end_date+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+value1.task_start_date+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+value1.task_end_date+"</td>"+
                                "</tr>";
                            }); //end of each
                            project +=
                        "</table>"+
                    "</div>";
                }); //end of each
                $("#projectDetail").append(project);
                $('table.Layer1Table').DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    dom: 'Bfltip',
                    buttons: [
                        { extend: 'excelHtml5' }
                    ],
                    destroy: true,
                    ordering: true,
                    columnDefs: [
                        { type: 'date-eu', targets: 1 }  //example target for planned start date
                    ],
                });
            }
            else {}
        },
        error: function(e){}
    });
}
```

Comment: Best thing is you keep date in format YYYYMMDD, then it is always alphabetical order able. You also could take this as an data-attribute and sort by that, whereas the display can be different.

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492249/datatables-cannot-sort-date-column-type-in-edge) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492249/datatables-cannot-sort-date-column-type-in-edge#comment107016149_60492249), for more related info and examples.

Answer (score 0):

notice that you are using date as **string** so it will sort this as normal string.

for your problem you can refer this  https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-uk

thank you!
Happy coding!